# Full width grid in ListView

Tags: xaml, windows-8.1

Here is my code:

```
    <Border BorderBrush="BlueViolet" BorderThickness="9">
    <ListView x:Name="lbEOParam" ItemsSource="{Binding}" 
              Margin="0,0,0,0"                   
              HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">

        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Border BorderBrush="Aqua" BorderThickness="7" >

                        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">

                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>                       
                              <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>


                    <Slider Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" 
                            Minimum="{Binding MinValueDevice}" 
                            Maximum="{Binding MaxValueDevice}" 
                            Value="{Binding Value, Mode=TwoWay}"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                            VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                            Margin="0 0 0 0"></Slider>

                </Grid>
                </Border>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
    </Border>


</Grid>
```

And here is a result:

[image]

Why my sliders don't have full width ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set `ListViewItem`'s `HorizontalContentAlignment` property to `Stretch` to make it stretches across `ListView`'s width. For example, you can set the property from `Style` like this :

```
<ListView x:Name="lbEOParam" ItemsSource="{Binding}" 
          Margin="0,0,0,0"                   
          HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    .......
</ListView>
```